# mysqldump version not matching Server version on Mac OSX

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mysql

I'm using MySql server on Mac OSX 10.6.7, and I've installed latest version of MySQL Workbench GUI to administrate it.  When I try to Export a database, I get a message about mysqldump being version 5.1.34 and therefore incompatible with the server whose version is 5.5.9.
How can I update the mysqldump version to be compatible with my server?
Thanks

Comment: How did you install your mysql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to trash what ever mysql server u have installed, and install it via Brew

[Link](https://brew.sh/)

You can also just install mysql from in addition to the one you are running however this isnt advised.

brew install mysql

hopefully the brew version will be new enough to support it.

Before dumping your old mysql install however, it might be a good idea to do an export via a tool like navicat.

Comment: can also install MySql using MacPorts: sudo port install mysql5 +server

Answer (score 10):

Look at the mysql installation folder. Most likely it is /usr/local/mysql/bin
You will find the mysqldump compatible to your mysql version. You need to tell mysqlworkbench to go and fetch mysqlworkbench from this location. To do that, open mysqlworkbench - preferences - admin

Comment: Worked well. The version bundled with MySQLWorkbench was old but my local MySQL server had the correct version. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had some problems to exactly know what and where to put the local path in the preferences.
here are some more detailed infos:

1- Go to mysqlworkbench and edit the preferences:
mysqlworkbench/preferences.../Administartion

2- Edit the "Path to mysqldump Tool:" field and select your local mysqldump
example: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21/bin/mysqldump